# How to generate database with table of variable number of columns?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my Android app, I need to temporarily store some data in a form of table such as follows:

id | column 1 | column 2 | ... | column n

The data are downloaded from a server whenever users press a button. However, the data table doesn't have a fix number of column (as well as row) every time user downloads it from the server. For example, the server may send data with 3 columns the first time. Then it might send data with 5 columns the second time, etc...

Given this scenario, I think the database is probably the right data structure to use. My plan is to create a database, then add and delete tables as necessary. So I have been reading various tutorials on Android database (one example is this one http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android#). It seems to me I cannot create new table with variable number of columns using the sqlite database. Is this correct? In the onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method, the "create table" command must be specified with known number of columns and their data types. I could provide several "create table" commands, each with different number of columns but that seems like very crude. Is there a way to create database tables with variable number of columns on the fly?

Another alternative probably using several hash tables, each storing one column of the data table. I'm seriously considering this approach if the database approach is not possible. Any better suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such thing as a variable number of columns in an SQLite data base. Also, adding and deleting tables dynamically seems like a horrible hack.

It sounds like you want to store an array of values associated with an id. I suggest you think in terms of rows, not columns. Use a table structure like (id, index, value); each array of values returned by the server results in as many rows as necessary to store the values.

Comment: +1 The type of db model Ted is describing is known as EAV: Entity Attribute Value - See Wikipedia for an overview: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: This is the answer you need, it's about the design type.

Comment: hmm... this might work although the coding to access the table might be more complicated than what i was hoping to do. what is your opinion of this approach compared to having multiple hash tables?

Comment: @ciklee - I don't really understand your multiple hash tables approach. How would you have persistence?

Comment: i only need to store the downloaded data temporarily for processing, thus it doesn't need persistence. using the database approach, i would create a table, populate it with downloaded data, process them and delete the table. using the hash table approach, i would create multiple hash tables based on number of columns in the downloaded data, process them and clear the hash tables. hope this is clear.

Comment: @ciklee - For the hash table approach, why not make a single hash that maps an id to an ArrayList of values? That seems less cumbersome than juggling multiple hash tables.